# Error converting from VB.NET to C#. Non-Invocable member 'DataSet.Tables'

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

Right now I am working on a project where I am converting a VB.NET code to C#.
I have used https://converter.telerik.com/, which I have heard is quite accurate. Which it mostly is, but now I have approached a error: *non-invocable member 'dataset.tables' cannot be used like a method*.

This is my first converting ever so I have it quite hard to see what is wrong with just this line of code.

Heres the VB.NET sample:

```
RcdCount = da.Tables("pubs").Rows.Count.ToString()
```

Here is the C# sample:

```
RcdCount = da.Tables("pubs").Rows.Count.ToString();
```

As you can see, the only change that is made is the ";" at the end.
How do I solve this?

Comment: In C# arrays are enclosed in square brackets _ds.Tables["pubs"]...._

Comment: @Steve In this case, I'm sure it's an indexer rather than an array (since it's a string rather than an integer argument).  Of course, the indexer syntax is based on array syntax.

Answer (score 3):

As it seems, `Tables` is an indexer, therefore square brackets must be used:

```
RcdCount = da.Tables["pubs"].Rows.Count.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, Of course. Tried that earlier I think and then it didn´t work but when I copied yours it worked perfectly fine. :)

Comment: @Craig Absolutely correct. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already found the answer you were looking for. But if you still want to take a look, I tested the code sample on this site and it translated correctly.

[carlosag.net](https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/)